# shiro + cas4.0 Into subsystem error in cas after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cas, shiro

follows：

jasig cas 4.0 + shiro 1.2.1 +spring 3.2.1

client configuration file is as follows:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <property name="loginUrl" value="https://sso.h-guiyang.com:8443/cas/login?service=https://admin.h-guiyang.com:8081/admin/" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="https://admin.h-guiyang.com:8081/admin/"></property>  
    <property name="filters">
        <map>

            <entry key="casFilter" value-ref="casFilter"/>



        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /admin/management/index = casFilter
            /ehrLoginSSO/**= anon
            /unauthorized = anon
            /loginSSO/**= anon
            /Captcha.jpg = anon
            /styles/** = anon
            /ws/** = anon 
            /resources/** = anon
            /styles/** = anon
            /login/timeout = anon
            <!-- /login = authc -->
            /logout = logout
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="casSubjectFactory" class="org.apache.shiro.cas.CasSubjectFactory"/>
<!-- Shiro's main business-tier object for web-enabled applications -->
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="shiroDbRealm" />
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="shiroEhcacheManager" />

    <property name="subjectFactory" ref="casSubjectFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="shiroDbRealm" class="net.hp.es.adm.healthcare.rphcp.shiro.ShiroDbCasRealm" depends-on="userDAO, userRoleDAO, organizationRoleDAO, roleDAO">
    <property name="userService" ref="userServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="userRoleService" ref="userRoleServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="roleService" ref="roleServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="organizationRoleService" ref="organizationRoleServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="casServerUrlPrefix" value="https://sso.h-guiyang.com:8443/cas"/>
    <property name="casService" value="https://admin.h-guiyang.com:8081/admin"/>

    <property name="useCaptcha" value="false"/>

    <property name="activeRoot" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="casFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.cas.CasFilter">
    <property name="failureUrl" value="/unauthorized"/>
</bean>

<bean id="shiroEhcacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManagerConfigFile" value="classpath:ehcache/ehcache-shiro.xml"/>
</bean>

  <bean id="dWZUserFilter" class="net.hp.es.adm.healthcare.rphcp.shiro.DWZUserFilter"/>

<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

When I from CAS login successfully into the subsystem,subsystem shiro error as follows：

```
org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException: Attempting to perform a user-only operation.  The current Subject is not a user (they haven't been authenticated or remembered from a previous login).  Access denied.
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.UserAnnotationHandler.assertAuthorized(UserAnnotationHandler.java:61) ~[shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:84) ~[shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.java:100) ~[shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingMethodInterceptor.java:38) ~[shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AopAllianceAnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.invoke(AopAllianceAnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[shiro-spring-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at net.hp.es.adm.healthcare.rphcp.controller.IndexController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e57cb6e1.index(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:176) [spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:203) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.68]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.68]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException: Not authorized to invoke method: public java.lang.String net.hp.es.adm.healthcare.rphcp.controller.IndexController.index(java.util.Map)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:90) ~[shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
... 62 common frames omitted

2016-03-23 10:12:27,808 [http-bio-8081-exec-3] ERROR 500.jsp - org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException: Attempting to perform a user-only operation.  The current Subject is not a user (they haven't been authenticated or remembered from a previous login).  Access denied.
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.UserAnnotationHandler.assertAuthorized(UserAnnotationHandler.java:61)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:84)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.java:100)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingMethodInterceptor.java:38)
at org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AopAllianceAnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.invoke(AopAllianceAnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at net.hp.es.adm.healthcare.rphcp.controller.IndexController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e57cb6e1.index(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:203)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException: Not authorized to invoke method: public java.lang.String net.hp.es.adm.healthcare.rphcp.controller.IndexController.index(java.util.Map)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:90)
... 62 more
```

ShiroDbrealm code :

```
public class ShiroDbCasRealm extends CasRealm {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShiroDbCasRealm.class);
private static final int INTERATIONS = 1024;
private static final int SALT_SIZE = 8;
private static final String ALGORITHM = "SHA-1";


protected boolean activeRoot = false;


protected boolean useCaptcha = false;
@Autowired
protected UserService userService;
@Autowired
private RolePermissionService rolePermissionService;
@Autowired
protected RoleService roleService;
@Autowired
protected UserRoleService userRoleService;
@Autowired
protected OrganizationRoleService organizationRoleService;


public ShiroDbCasRealm() {
    HashedCredentialsMatcher matcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher(ALGORITHM);
    matcher.setHashIterations(INTERATIONS);

    setCredentialsMatcher(matcher);
}


@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    System.out.println("================");
    CasToken casToken = (CasToken) authcToken;
    if (authcToken == null)
        return null;
    String ticket = (String) casToken.getCredentials();
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(ticket))
        return null;
    TicketValidator ticketValidator = ensureTicketValidator();
    try {
        Assertion casAssertion = ticketValidator.validate(ticket, getCasService());
        AttributePrincipal casPrincipal = casAssertion.getPrincipal();
        String userId = casPrincipal.getName();
        log.debug("Validate ticket : {} in CAS server : {} to retrieve user : {}",
                new Object[] { ticket, getCasServerUrlPrefix(), userId });
        Map attributes = casPrincipal.getAttributes();
        casToken.setUserId(userId);
        User user = userService.getByUsername(userId);
        if (user != null) {
            if (user.getStatus().equals(User.STATUS_DISABLED)) {
                throw new DisabledAccountException();
            }
            byte[] salt = Encodes.decodeHex(user.getSalt());

            ShiroUser shiroUser = new ShiroUser(user.getId(), user.getUsername());
            shiroUser.setUser(userService.get(shiroUser.getId()));

            return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(shiroUser, user.getPassword(), ByteSource.Util.bytes(salt),
                    getName());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // String rememberMeAttributeName = getRememberMeAttributeName();
        // String rememberMeStringValue = (String)
        // attributes.get(rememberMeAttributeName);
        // boolean isRemembered = rememberMeStringValue != null &&
        // Boolean.parseBoolean(rememberMeStringValue);
        // if (isRemembered)
        // casToken.setRememberMe(true);
        // List principals = CollectionUtils.asList(new Object[] { userId,
        // attributes });
        // PrincipalCollection principalCollection = new
        // SimplePrincipalCollection(principals, getName());
        // return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(principalCollection, ticket);
    } catch (TicketValidationException e) {
        throw new CasAuthenticationException(
                (new StringBuilder()).append("Unable to validate ticket [").append(ticket).append("]").toString(),
                e);
    }
}


@Override
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    System.out.println((String) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal() + "我进来了~~~~~~~");
    Collection<String> hasPermissions = null;
    Collection<String> hasRoles = null;
    String username = (String) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal();
    User user = userService.getByUsername(username);
    ShiroUser shiroUser = new ShiroUser(user.getId(), user.getUsername());
    shiroUser.setUser(userService.get(shiroUser.getId()));
    List<UserRole> userRoles = userRoleService.findByUserId(shiroUser.getId());
    List<OrganizationRole> organizationRoles = organizationRoleService
            .findByOrganizationId(shiroUser.getUser().getOrganization().getId());
    Collection<Role> roles = getUserRoles(userRoles, organizationRoles);
    hasRoles = makeRoles(roles, shiroUser);
    hasPermissions = makePermissions(roles, shiroUser);
    SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    info.addRoles(hasRoles);
    info.addStringPermissions(hasPermissions);
    shiroUser.setAttribute("roleNames", hasRoles);

    // return newAuthorizationInfo(shiroUser);
    return info;
}

private SimpleAuthorizationInfo newAuthorizationInfo(ShiroUser shiroUser) {
    Collection<String> hasPermissions = null;
    Collection<String> hasRoles = null;

    // 是否启用超级管理员 && id==1为超级管理员，构造所有权限
    if (activeRoot && shiroUser.getId() == 1) {
        hasRoles = new HashSet<String>();
        Page page = new Page();
        page.setNumPerPage(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        List<Role> roles = roleService.findAll(page);

        for (Role role : roles) {
            hasRoles.add(role.getName());
        }

        hasPermissions = new HashSet<String>();
        hasPermissions.add("*");

        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("使用了" + shiroUser.getLoginName() + "的超级管理员权限:" + "。At " + new Date());
            log.info(shiroUser.getLoginName() + "拥有的角色:" + hasRoles);
            log.info(shiroUser.getLoginName() + "拥有的权限:" + hasPermissions);
        }
    } else {
        List<UserRole> userRoles = userRoleService.findByUserId(shiroUser.getId());
        List<OrganizationRole> organizationRoles = organizationRoleService
                .findByOrganizationId(shiroUser.getUser().getOrganization().getId());

        Collection<Role> roles = getUserRoles(userRoles, organizationRoles);
        hasRoles = makeRoles(roles, shiroUser);
        hasPermissions = makePermissions(roles, shiroUser);
    }

    SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    info.addRoles(hasRoles);
    info.addStringPermissions(hasPermissions);
    shiroUser.setAttribute("roleNames", hasRoles);
    return info;
}

private Collection<Role> getUserRoles(List<UserRole> userRoles, List<OrganizationRole> organizationRoles) {
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        roles.add(userRole.getRole());
    }

    for (OrganizationRole organizationRole : organizationRoles) {
        roles.add(organizationRole.getRole());
    }

    return roles;
}


private Collection<String> makeRoles(Collection<Role> roles, ShiroUser shiroUser) {
    Collection<String> hasRoles = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Role role : roles) {
        hasRoles.add(role.getName());
    }

    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info(shiroUser.getLoginName() + "拥有的角色:" + hasRoles);
    }
    return hasRoles;
}


private Collection<String> makePermissions(Collection<Role> roles, ShiroUser shiroUser) {
    // 清空shiroUser中map
    shiroUser.getHasDataControls().clear();
    shiroUser.getHasModules().clear();

    Collection<String> stringPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Role role : roles) {
        List<RolePermission> rolePermissions = role.getRolePermissions();
        for (RolePermission rolePermission : rolePermissions) {
            Permission permission = rolePermission.getPermission();

            String resource = permission.getModule().getSn();
            String operate = permission.getSn();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(resource + ":" + operate);

            shiroUser.getHasModules().put(resource, permission.getModule());

            // StringBuilder dcBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            // for (RolePermissionDataControl rpdc :
            // rolePermission.getRolePermissionDataControls()) {
            // DataControl dataControl = rpdc.getDataControl();
            // dcBuilder.append(dataControl.getName() + ",");
            //
            // shiroUser.getHasDataControls().put(dataControl.getName(),
            // dataControl);
            // }

            // if (dcBuilder.length() > 0) {
            // builder.append(":" + dcBuilder.substring(0,
            // dcBuilder.length() - 1));
            // }
            //
            stringPermissions.add(builder.toString());
        }
    }

    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info(shiroUser.getLoginName() + "拥有的权限:" + stringPermissions);
    }
    return stringPermissions;
}

public static class HashPassword {
    public String salt;
    public String password;
}

public static HashPassword encryptPassword(String plainPassword) {
    HashPassword result = new HashPassword();
    byte[] salt = Digests.generateSalt(SALT_SIZE);
    result.salt = Encodes.encodeHex(salt);

    byte[] hashPassword = Digests.sha1(plainPassword.getBytes(), salt, INTERATIONS);
    result.password = Encodes.encodeHex(hashPassword);
    return result;
}


public static boolean validatePassword(String plainPassword, String password, String salt) {
    byte[] hashPassword = Digests.sha1(plainPassword.getBytes(), Encodes.decodeHex(salt), INTERATIONS);
    String oldPassword = Encodes.encodeHex(hashPassword);
    return password.equals(oldPassword);
}


@Override
protected Object getAuthorizationCacheKey(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    ShiroUser shiroUser = (ShiroUser) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal();
    return shiroUser.getLoginName();
}


public void clearCachedAuthorizationInfo(String loginName) {
    ShiroUser shiroUser = new ShiroUser(loginName);

    SimplePrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(shiroUser, getName());
    clearCachedAuthorizationInfo(principals);
}

public void clearAllCachedAuthorizationInfo() {
    Cache<Object, AuthorizationInfo> cache = getAuthorizationCache();
    if (cache != null) {
        for (Object key : cache.keys()) {
            cache.remove(key);
        }
    }
}


public void setActiveRoot(boolean activeRoot) {
    this.activeRoot = activeRoot;
}

/**
 * 设置 useCaptcha 的值
 * 
 * @param useCaptcha
 */
public void setUseCaptcha(boolean useCaptcha) {
    this.useCaptcha = useCaptcha;
}

public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}


public void setUserRoleService(UserRoleService userRoleService) {
    this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
}

/**
 * 设置 organizationRoleService 的值
 * 
 * @param organizationRoleService
 */
public void setOrganizationRoleService(OrganizationRoleService organizationRoleService) {
    this.organizationRoleService = organizationRoleService;
}

/**
 * @param roleService
 *            the roleService to set
 */
public void setRoleService(RoleService roleService) {
    this.roleService = roleService;
}
```

}

How can I solve this problem, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

shiro-cas module is now deprecated in Shiro: you should use: https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j instead.
That said, I'm a bit confused by your configuration: how the redirection to CAS is trigered? The casFilter should be configured on a callback url...